# what is the best practice to handle form data in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, forms, controller, codeigniter-3

I am developing a new application in CodeIgniter. I already developed some applications in CI. In all my previous applications I used to handle form's like below :

My Controller: My_controller.php

```
class My_controller extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('my_model');
  }
  public function sign_up()
  {
    $this->load->view('sign_up');
  }
  public function do_sign_up()
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
      $this->load->view('sign_up');
    }
    else
    {
      $this->my_model->insert_user();
      $data['message'] = "Signup Successful";
      $this->load->view('sign_up', $data);
    }
  }
```

My View: sign_up.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <?php echo form_open("my_controller/do_sign_up"); ?>

  form elements comes here.....
  ...............................

 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a doubt that is 2 methods sign_up() & do_sign_up() required in the controller to handle just one sign_up form. If I write code like this to handle each form then the number of methods in the controller will increase. is this right way? or is there any other way of doing this? Can anyone please help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely use one function. Something like below.

```
 public function sign_up()
 {
   if ($this->input->post()) {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('');
      if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
      {
         $this->load->view('sign_up');
      }
      else
      {
         $this->my_model->insert_user();
         $data['message'] = "Signup Successful";
         $this->load->view('sign_up', $data);
      }
   }else{
      $this->load->view('sign_up');
   }
```

}

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This will work for sure but I want know what is the best practices to handle forms data?

Answer (score 0):

you can also set this way

```
    public function registre()
{


$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','EMAIL','trim|required|valid_email');

if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
    {
        echo validation_errors();
        $this->load->view('sign_up');//load page
   or you can      redirect('welcome/index');//also redirect
    }
    else{
        $data=array(
            'email'=>$this->input->post('email')
            );

           $this->welcome_model->registre($data);


        echo "<div class='alert'>Inscription success</div>";
        redirect('welcome/index');
    }
}
```

i think following the documentation is best practice https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#form-validation-tutorial

Comment: what if I don't use codeigniter's form validations instead if I use my own jQuery validations.

Comment: you can do it,but codeigniter form validation is more secure than jQuery validation@prasadchinthala

Answer (score 0):

For my view best practice to handle  data in CodeIgniter (for all other framework as well)

1.Assign value to variable in controller

2.Initialize an array from those variable

3.Use codeigniter form validation to validate user inputs 
     (should do atleast type and length validation)

4.Use callback for user defined validation ,if required

5.Also do isset() and !empty() method call for all data returned 
   form functions (this will check whether data variable is set or it has 
   an  empty value)

6.For front-end validation(client-side validation) we can use either html
   or jquery validation.Code visibility is the main disadvantage
   For back-end(server-side) validation most of the time we use modules and
   libraries supported by corresponding frameworks

7.Better programming practice have both front-end and back-end validation